# Can kerberos admin-server be on different machine than KDC?

Tags: kerberos

I'm currently learning about Kerberos, and there's something I don't quite understand: Seemingly, the admin-server: `kadmind` - doesn't HAVE to run on the same machine as of the KDC. But that sounds weird - since `kadmind` does changes to the database by directly accessing the database file `principal` or `principal.ok` (Don't sure the exactly which does what but overall they're the ones that hold the database itself).

So I can understand that I can run administrative tasks from other machines using `kadmin` - the kadmin util just communicates with the `kadmind` running on the primary KDC machine. But how can it be that the `kadmind` itself runs on another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one possibility is that the machine with `kadmind` **could have its own copy** of the database, the master copy, and all KDCs only have replicas of it.

Both MIT Krb5 and Heimdal Kerberos have replication tools, such as `kpropd`, to build redundant KDC clusters. So in the simplest case, you could have three KDCs but only one of them running kadmind, with `kprop` being used to transfer changes. (KDCs themselves don't make permanent DB updates, aside from optionally tracking the "last login" times, so replication can be unidirectional.)

In the same way you can also have a setup similar to "stealth master" in DNS, where the primary copy is managed from a machine that's not exposed to clients, and all changes are pushed out to KDCs via kprop (or rsync, or basic dump+load via SSH).

Another possibility is that the KDC is **not using the file-based BerkeleyDB storage** in the first place. Both MIT Kerberos and Heimdal can actually use *an LDAP server* as the KDC database, and once you have that, the `kadmind` process can connect to the LDAP server remotely – there would be no `principal` file at all.

(Several LDAP servers also support multi-master replication, which can be used to make *all* replicas writable, e.g. you could have 3 machines running OpenLDAP + KDC + kadmind, all of them equally "primary".

Indeed if you look at Microsoft's Active Directory, it is based entirely around an LDAP directory that holds all the information – including KDC and DNS data – and all DCs replicate changes in all directions. It has no separate 'kadmin' process; instead Kerberos principals are created via LDAP as part of the overall user or mcahine account, and you can just create that entry on whichever DC you like.)